# Access File Directory From Sharepoint Server Using Java - Checking Permissions

Tags: java, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

programmers. Can you please help me? To preface, I'm a first-year intern and the company I work for wants me to write a program that checks if the files on SharePoint are locked or unlocked, and if they are locked, run a PowerShell script to unlock the file and state who it was locked by (so this information is under permissions on SharePoint). The PowerShell script is already done, but I'm have A LOT of trouble with the Java program. I just don't understand how to do it. Please help - this is my first internship and I really don't want to disappoint.

So, since I didn't know how to get the folders, I wrote a simple program to index all the files and folders in a user specified directory (just to get a simple idea of what the hell I'm doing). Now, How would I change the program so I can instead index the SharePoint directory? Please try to explain your solutions as well - I want to learn.

Honestly, even if you can show me an ugly way to do this (i.e. download all the files in a directory and then index them to see if they were locked, and who locked them), I'd be over the moon. Just, please help...

Here is a code snippet I wrote using TreeView. I know it's not that good or optimized - I'm still relatively new to Java, and I just want it to work:

```
    private File user_filedirectory() throws Exception {
    String directory_name;
    directory_name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a file directory: ", "File Directory", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    boolean bool_directory;
    bool_directory = false;
    boolean bool_exists;
    bool_exists = false;

    String path;
    path = null;
    File f;
    f = null;

    f = new File(directory_name);
    bool_directory = f.isDirectory();
    bool_exists = f.exists();

    path = f.getPath();

    if (!(bool_exists || bool_directory)) {
        showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid File Directory! Close Alert and Try Again...", "Invalid File Directory", ERROR_MESSAGE);
        return user_filedirectory();
    } else return f;
}

private void createNodes(DefaultMutableTreeNode node, File f) {

    if (!f.isDirectory()) {
        out.printf("FILE - %s%n", f.getName());
        DefaultMutableTreeNode child;
        child = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(f);
        node.add(child);
    } else {
        out.printf("DIRECTORY - %s%n", f.getName());
        DefaultMutableTreeNode child;
        child = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(f);
        node.add(child);
        File[] fList;
        fList = f.listFiles();
        if (fList == null);
        File[] requireNonNull;
        requireNonNull = requireNonNull(fList);
        for (int i = 0, requireNonNullLength = requireNonNull.length; i < requireNonNullLength; i++) {
            File aRequireNonNull;
            aRequireNonNull = requireNonNull[i];
            File aFList;
            aFList = aRequireNonNull;
            createNodes(child, aFList);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason it needs to be done in Java instead of through PowerShell? SharePoint is a .NET web application; PowerShell (or any executable written in .NET, for that matter) executed from a SharePoint web front end server can natively communicate with SharePoint using its server object model. Microsoft has also published a [.NET client object model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee537855%28v=office.14%29.aspx) so you can interact with it via .NET apps remotely, as well as web services and REST endpoints if you want to talk to it from something other than .NET code.

Comment: The only reason I'm doing it through Java is because I don't know PowerShell. The PowerShell script was written a while back, but the bosses want a GUI with an explorer where they select the file and the program tells them if it locked or not. I know PHP and C++ as well.

Comment: If you're stuck with Java, you might want to explore whether your directory-indexing code understands UNC file paths. For example, if your SharePoint library is located at `http://contoso.com/site/library`, you could access it through Windows File Explorer with the UNC path `\\contoso.com\site\library`. This is dependent on a service (such as WebClient/WebDAV) running on your local computer that is able to interpret the web directory as if it were a local directory.

Comment: @Thriggle Wow, I honestly did not know that was possible! I'll get right on that! Thank you so much. WebDAV does run on all the machines at work, so I hope the code I have is able to interpret those paths.